Do all usb hdd enclosures work with ubuntu
So i want to buy hdd enclosure that fits 4 hdds and use it on my ubuntu install. Problem is for enclosure that i want to buy windows is listed as only supported OS. Hdd enclosure name is lc power LC-DOCK-U3-4B. I want to know if it will work with my ubutnu even though it officially only supports windows.

I've purchased PC accessories in the past which only listed Windoze but which worked with Linux w/o needing any additional drivers. If you are uncertain, buy from a source which will allow return of the item if you discover issues.

Sadly in my country there is only return policy if product doesn't work

this article specifically lists it as working with Linux.

Thanks for finding this
